# ¿Por qué %2 parece ser igual a %2 ==1 en este programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este programa pide 10 enteros al usuario y arroja el valor impar más alto:

```
maxOdd = None
for x in range(10):
    value = int(input('Enter a value: '))
    if (value % 2 and (maxOdd is None or value > maxOdd)): #for some reason value % 2 is equal to express value % 2== 1 or value % 2 != 0
        maxOdd = value
if maxOdd:
    print('The largest odd value entered was', maxOdd)
else:
  print('No odd values were entered.')
```

Tampoco estoy seguro de la diferencia entre poner None en vez de 0.

Answer (score 3):

El condiccional `if` evalua una operación logica, es decir una expresión que de como resultado un boleano (true o false) y ejecuta la pieza de código siguiente siempre y cuando el resultado sea verdadero.

Tu duda viene porque la operación módulo retorna un entero no un valor boleano. La explicación es simple, un entero se considera `False` cuando es igual a 0 y `True` en cualquier otro caso. Estas normas también existen para otros objetos, por ejemplo una lista/tupla/set/diccionario es considerado `False` si esta vacía, una cadena es evaluada como `False` si es una cadena vacía, etc. Podemos comprobar esto fácilmente haciendo un casting a tipo boleano con `bool()`:

```
>>> bool(0)
>>> False
>>> bool(-1)
>>> True
>>> bool(0.000)
>>> False
>>> bool([])
>>> False
>>> bool([1,2,3])
>>> True
>>> bool('')
>>> False
>>> bool('HolaNundo')
>>> True
```

Todo objeto en Python tiene un valor boleano asociado, la norma general es:

- Son evaluados como False:

  - `None`
  - `False`
  - 0 (integer, float o complex)
  - Colecciones vacías: `“”`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`
  - Objetos de clases que tiene implementado el método especial  `__nonzero__`
  - Objetos de clases que implemntan el método  `__len__` para retornar `False` o cero.
- El resto de objetos son evaluados como `True`.

El `if` simplemente considera si lo que hay delante es falso o verdadero. Si no es una expresión que retorne un valor boleano como son los operadores boleanos (`==`, `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<`, `!=` ) se evalua según las normas anteriores, que en realidad no son más que convenciones. En este caso si el entero no es 0 se evalua como `True`.

La operación `%2` va a retornar siempre 0 o 1 ya que esos son los dos únicos restos posibles de la división entera entre 2. Por eso `%2 == 1` es válida también.

En cuanto al uso de `None` ó 0 en este caso no hay grandes diferencias. `None` ocupa menos en memoria pero eso carece de importancia alguna en tu código realmente. En lo que si hay diferencia es en que si usas 0 puedes simplificar el condicional. `None` no permite usar el operador `>` pero 0 si, esto permite eliminar el `or`:

```
maxOdd = 0
for x in range(10):
    value = int(input('Enter a value: '))
    if (value % 2 and value > maxOdd):
        maxOdd = value
if maxOdd:
    print('The largest odd value entered was', maxOdd)
else:
  print('No odd values were entered.')
```

El `if-else` final funciona igual por lo explicado al principio, si es 0 se evalua como `False` igual que hace con `None`.